# Vertical parallel lines/arrows

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

How can I draw with `tikz-cd`

1. two vertical parallel lines
2. two vertical parallel lines pointing in opposite directions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
A\arrow[transform canvas={xshift=0.3ex},-]{d} \arrow[transform canvas={xshift=-0.4ex},-]{d} & B\arrow[transform canvas={xshift=0.9ex}]{d} \\
C  & D \arrow[transform canvas={xshift=-0.4ex}]{u} 
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option for the double lines would be to the `equal` arrow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
A\arrow[equal]{d} & B\arrow[transform canvas={xshift=0.9ex}]{d} \\
C  & D \arrow[transform canvas={xshift=-0.4ex}]{u} 
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Use the same shifting value if equal separation is desired; in the following example the arrows to the left will be 0.7ex to the left of the north anchor and the arrows to the right will be 0.7ex to the right of the north anchor (instead of `0.7ex` you can use any other valid length, according to your needs):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
A\arrow[transform canvas={xshift=0.7ex},-]{d} \arrow[transform canvas={xshift=-0.7ex},-]{d} & B\arrow[transform canvas={xshift=0.7ex}]{d} \\
C  & D \arrow[transform canvas={xshift=-0.7ex}]{u} 
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By default, `tikz-cd` uses `\scriptstyle` for the labels; if you want to change this, you can use the labels key to use, for example, `\textstyle`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\tikzset{commutative diagrams/diagrams={%
  labels={font=\everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath\textstyle}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow{r}{\eta} & B \\
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The arrows and the lines are just like this. But it's a commutative diagram with an arrow joining A and B and another one joining C and D.

Comment: @olurodekaa please explain in more detail. I don't understand your comment. In your question you mentioned parallel lines and now your comment refers to single arrows? Where should the nodes A, B, C and D appear? In the same row? In two different rows?

Comment: the double line (space in-between) between A and C seem thinner compared to that between B and D. Will prefer the 2 to be equally spaced. How can i do this? And what is it that informs the choice of 0.3ex, 0.4ex, 0.9ex,...

Comment: @olurodekaa please see my updated answer. The choice of the length to use will depend on the contents of the specific nodes. The important part is to use "symmetric" values (the same value to the left and to the right). I choose `ex` as the unit to make the length font-size dependent. Sorry to bother you with this, but I see that you haven't up-voted nor accepted answers to your questions (up-voting and accepting are the way to say "thanks" around here). Please consider revisiting your questions and up-voting answers you consider good, and accepting the ones you consider solved your problems.

Comment: I have looked at the answers  and now, i'm ok. I eventually used bits of 2 of your answers. I didn't use the one with 'equal'. I used the one with '-' and replaced '-' with 'dash' and produced what i want. I do not understand how to upvote for now. can you guide me through doing so?

Comment: I also noticed that the labels on the arrows are very small in size. How can I increase the label font size?

Comment: @olurodekaa I updated my answer showing how to change the font size for the labels. Regarding the voting/accepting process, I see that you've already upvoted some answer now and that is good. The remaining step is to accept best answers. In each of your questions you can accept the answer that you consider best solved your problem; this is done by clicking on the check-mark to the left of the answer. In this link you can find detailed information: [`How do you accept an answer?`](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954)

Answer (score 2):

With PSTricks, it is just for fun!

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}
\offinterlineskip
$
\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=1,colsep=2,mnode=circle,shortput=tablr,nodesep=2pt]
    Left & Right
\ncline[offset=3pt]{->}{1,1}{1,2}^{above}
\ncline[offset=-3pt]{<-}{1,1}{1,2}_{below}
\end{psmatrix}
$
\qquad
$
\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=1,colsep=2,mnode=circle,shortput=tablr,nodesep=2pt]
    Top \\
    Bottom
\ncline[offset=3pt]{->}{1,1}{2,1}>{right}
\ncline[offset=-3pt]{<-}{1,1}{2,1}<{left}
\end{psmatrix}
$
\end{document}
```

### Warning:

As far as I know, the radius of circle node cannot be adjusted to be uniform.

Answer (score 0):

The TikZ-CD package/library nowadays come with keys called `shift left` and `shift right`.

They accept:

1. no argument,
2. a factor (without units) and
3. a dimension (with units).

The key will shift the line orthogonally to the line connecting the original start and end coordinate (usually a point on the border of the nodes) by

1. the default value for `shift left` which is, by default, 0.56ex,
2. said default value multiplied by the given factor or
3. the given length.

Nodes along the arrow (called labels by TikZ-CD) will be placed along the new shifted path not the unshifted one.

---

The first diagram in the code below shows

- two parallel lines without an arrow tip between *A* and *C*,
- two parallel forward arrows (between *B* and *D*) where one is drawn from *B* to *D* and one from *D* to *B* (both with `shift left`) and
- two parallel arrows drawn from *C* to *B* where one has reversed arrow tips (`leftarrow`).

In the second diagram I show how the shifting works:
[image]

The gray line is the direct connections between the nodes.
The thin green line is the unshifted curve whereas the thick green line is the shifted one.

The blue dashed line shows the connection between start and end point of the curve, the blue arrows show the shifting direction (orthogonal to the dashed line).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  A \ar[d, dash, shift left] \ar[d, dash, shift right]
& B \ar[d, shift left]\\
  C \ar[u, dash, shift left]
    \ar[ur, shift left]
    \ar[ur, shift right, leftarrow]
& D \ar[u, shift left]
\end{tikzcd}
\begin{tikzcd}[
  cells={nodes={draw, help lines}}, /tikz/>={Stealth[scale=.5]},
  /tikz/c/.style={shape=coordinate, name={#1}}, column sep=tiny, arrows=dash]
    & A \\
  B \ar[ur, help lines]
    \ar[ur, out=90, in=270, help lines, green,
        "" {at start, c=A }, "" {at end, c=B }]
    \ar[ur, out=90, in=270, shift left=3, green, thick,
        "" {at start, c=A'}, "" {at end, c=B'}]
    \ar[help lines, from=A, to=B, dashed, blue]
    \ar[help lines, blue, from=A, to=A', ->]
    \ar[help lines, blue, from=B, to=B', ->]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: There's also other approaches possible if you need [a lot of these parallel arrows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/671225).