# Many arrows with alternating directions stacked on top of each other with tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

When you draw simplicial diagrams in mathematics, the result often looks something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\tikzcdset{
  diagrams={>={Straight Barb[scale=0.5]}}
}

\begin{document}

Consider the simplicial set~\( X_{\bullet} \) given by
\[\begin{tikzcd}
    \cdots
    \ar[r,yshift=6pt,->]
    \ar[r,yshift=4.5pt,<-]
    \ar[r,yshift=3pt,->]
    \ar[r,yshift=1.5pt,<-]
    \ar[r,yshift=0pt,->]
    \ar[r,yshift=-1.5pt,<-]
    \ar[r,yshift=-3pt,->]
    \ar[r,yshift=-4.5pt,<-]
    \ar[r,yshift=-6pt,->]
    &
    X_3
    \ar[r,yshift=4.5pt,->]
    \ar[r,yshift=3pt,<-]
    \ar[r,yshift=1.5pt,->]
    \ar[r,yshift=0pt,<-]
    \ar[r,yshift=-1.5pt,->]
    \ar[r,yshift=-3pt,<-]
    \ar[r,yshift=-4.5pt,->]
    &
    X_2
    \ar[r,yshift=3pt,->]
    \ar[r,yshift=1.5pt,<-]
    \ar[r,yshift=0pt,->]
    \ar[r,yshift=-1.5pt,<-]
    \ar[r,yshift=-3pt,->]
    &   
    X_1
    \ar[r,yshift=1.5pt,->]
    \ar[r,yshift=0pt,<-]
    \ar[r,yshift=-1.5pt,->]
    &
    X_0
\end{tikzcd}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I wonder if there is a way to automate this? E.g. could we define a key `stack` such that `stack=n` stacked `n` arrows on top of each other with alternating directions, with the top one going in the “forward” direction.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\tikzcdset{
  diagrams={>={Straight Barb[scale=0.5]}}
}

\tikzset{
    stack/.style={
        %insert code
    }
}

\begin{document}

Consider the simplicial set~\( X_{\bullet} \) given by
\[\begin{tikzcd}
    \cdots
    \ar[r,stack=9]
    &
    X_3
    \ar[r,stack=7]
    &
    X_2
    \ar[r,stack=5]
    &   
    X_1
    \ar[r,stack=3]
    &
    X_0
\end{tikzcd}\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is using `tikz-cd` mandatory? Because it would be pretty easy to do it in plain TikZ, I think, with some `foreach` and using `ifthenelse`.

Comment: @SebGlav Not mandatory, but preferred. But any solution is certainly appreciated. But if it’s easy in `tikz`, shouldn’t it also be somehow possible in `tikz-cd`?

Comment: I get some issues with inserting `foreach` and variables into the `tikz-cd` syntax which I'm not very used to. If you don't get any satisfying answer (which I certainly doubt), I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Updated Solution

After considering [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/670947/125871) I realized the `pathreplacing` library can be used to create new arrows that can be incorporated into a `tikzcd`. Here is an updated solution that allows the command `\arrow[r, altstackar=7]` inside a `tikzcd`. Any direction will work. The linked question also has code for multiple arrows in one direction.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, calc}

\tikzcdset{
  diagrams={>={Straight Barb[scale=0.5]}}
}
\tikzset{
  altstackar/.style={decorate, decoration={show path construction,
    lineto code={
      \path (\tikzinputsegmentfirst); \pgfgetlastxy{\xstart}{\ystart}
      \path (\tikzinputsegmentlast); \pgfgetlastxy{\xend}{\yend}
      \path ($(0,0)!1.5pt!(\ystart-\yend,\xend-\xstart)$); \pgfgetlastxy{\xperp}{\yperp}
      \foreach \n[evaluate=\n as \k using .5*#1-\n+.5] in {1,...,#1}{
        \ifodd\n{\draw[->, shorten <=2pt, shift={($\k*(\xperp,\yperp)$)}](\xstart,\ystart)--(\xend,\yend);}
        \else{\draw[<-, shorten >=2pt, shift={($\k*(\xperp,\yperp)$)}](\xstart,\ystart)--(\xend,\yend);}\fi
      }
    }
  }}, altstackar/.default={1}
}


\begin{document}

\[\begin{tikzcd}
    \dotsb\arrow[r, altstackar=7] & X_2\arrow[r, altstackar=5] & X_1\arrow[r, altstackar=3] & X_0
\end{tikzcd}\]

\end{document}
```

### Old Solution

Here is an automated `tikz` solution. Arrow handling in `tikz-cd` is more complicated.

[image]

The call for the above image is

```
\cdots\stack{9}X_3\stack{7}X_2\stack{5}X_1\stack{3}X_0
```

The spacing between arrows is adjustable globally by setting `\stackspace`. Unit is `pt`. The length of the arrows is an optional argument in `\stack` with default `1cm`. So `\stack[.5]{3}` would give you 1/2 cm arrows. You can adjust the space around the arrows by replacing the `\;` commands with your preferred horizontal space, e.g., `\hspace{2mm}`.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\stackspace}{1.5}
\newcommand{\stack}[2][1cm]{\;\tikz[baseline, yshift=.65ex]%
    {\foreach \k [evaluate=\k as \r using (.5*#2+.5-\k)*\stackspace] in {1,...,#2}{%
    \ifodd\k{\draw[->](0,\r pt)--(#1,\r pt);}%
    \else{\draw[<-](0,\r pt)--(#1,\r pt);}\fi
    }}\;}

\begin{document}

\[
\cdots\stack{9}X_3\stack{7}X_2\stack{5}X_1\stack{3}X_0
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I like very much and there is also a clear and short code. +1

Comment: In principle, it would also be possible to create a macro `\stackar` which could be used inside a `tikz-cd` environment and expand to `tikz-cd` syntax, right? Possibly in a way that would support keyval syntax (to be passed on to the command `\ar`).

Comment: One thing I’ve been wondering: Is there a way allow the syntax `\ar[r,<-,stack=7]` as well where the top arrow then goes in the left direction? I.e. instead of hardcoding the direction of each arrow, could it simply start with the default direction and then “change direction” each time? I wonder how much more complicated the code would then become? (Note that I left the same comment to @Qrrbrbirlbel’s answer.)

Comment: @Gaussler: In the updated solution you can use the syntax `\arrow[from=r, altstackar=7]`.

Comment: I’m wondering if we can modify a bit the "Old Solution" to show only arrows to the right? I meant I want to draw one diagram with left arrows as in your "Old Solution", and then shortly after, one diagram without left arrows.

Answer (score 3):

With `shift left` TikZ-CD already has a mechanism built-in that can shift an arrow orthogonally to its direction.

---

The `stack` style loops over every one of those little arrows and applies the `shift left` style for each. I'm using `\pgfinteval` (i.e. `\numexpr`) here (which is PGF's own implementation of L3's `\inteval`) since it rounds the division to the nearest integer, meaning `(#1)/2` will always be (#1 + 1)/2.

The `shift left` mechanism hooks into `execute at begin to` which is the reasion why it must be specified *before* the `edge`. And since it uses the current `to path` that is needed to be set to `line to` before the `edge` as well (otherwise it would use the `to path` we're just defining which would result in an infinite loop/stack).

Instead of using the `edge` path directly, we need to expand `\tikztostart`/`\tikztotarget` because otherwise we would fall into a similar problem since it would try to do something like `\def\tikztostart{\tikztostart}` and that's no good.

Lastly, we'll apply either `stack/every even` or `stack/every odd`.

Inside `stack`, the default value of the `shift left` key (usually `.56ex`) will be set to the value of `stack distance`. This value will be multiplied with the result of the `\pgfinteval` expression above to get the final distance to be shifted. (You can also specify an absolute dimension which will ignore the default value.)

---

Though, instead of using `stack` directly, I'll suggest the styles `stack >` and `stack <` which set `stack/every odd` and `stack/every even` appropriately. This should make it rather easy to draw reversed arrows as long as it's only `>` (which could be redefined on-the-fly).

I've added a `stack alt` key that just swaps start and end points for the even arrows instead of swapping `->`/`<-` which makes it a bit easier to use any arrow tips but the shortening needs to be done manually then.

Finally, a key like `swap arrow tips` defined as

```
\makeatletter
\pgfset{
  swap arrow tips/.code=%
    \let\pgf@arrow@tip@sequence\pgf@end@tip@sequence
    \let\pgf@end@tip@sequence\pgf@start@tip@sequence
    \let\pgf@start@tip@sequence\pgf@arrow@tip@sequence}
\makeatother
```

can be used to reverse the arrow tip specification, though whether this is really necessary will depend on the complexity of the use-cases.

---

Notes:

1. The `shift left` does the whole evaluation for each arrow even though the base calculation is the same. This could be separated manually in two parts to speed up the process.
2. All styles will be applied in the TikZ namespace `/tikz` which makes it a bit harder to use keys from TikZ-CD (in the `/tikz/commutative diagrams` namespace) but I'm not sure which TikZ-CD keys can actually be used here.
3. Nodes along the stacked arrow will be gobbled.
4. I could see a `stack` style that somehow takes three arguments:

   1. the number of lines (mandatory)
   2. the inner `to path` that should be used (defaults to `line to`)
   3. the default distance between arrows (defaults to some other default distance, similar to `every stack`).

### Code

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzset{edges/.style={every edge/.append style={#1}}}
\tikzcdset{
  diagrams={>={Straight Barb[scale=0.5]}},
  stack distance/.initial=+.38ex,
  every stack/.style=,
  stacks/.style={/tikz/commutative diagrams/every stack/.append style={#1}},
  stack/do path/.style={
    /tikz/insert path/.expanded={(\tikztostart)edge(\tikztotarget)}},
  stack >/.style={
    /tikz/commutative diagrams/stack with setting=
      {->, shorten <=5\pgflinewidth}{<-, shorten >=5\pgflinewidth}{#1}},
  stack </.style={
    /tikz/commutative diagrams/stack with setting=
      {<-, shorten >=5\pgflinewidth}{->, shorten <=5\pgflinewidth}{#1}},
  stack/.style={
    /tikz/to path={foreach \stackArrow in {1,...,#1}{[
      commutative diagrams/shift left/.default=%
        \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/commutative diagrams/stack distance},
      commutative diagrams/shift left={\pgfinteval{\stackArrow-(#1)/2}},
      line to,
      commutative diagrams/every stack/.try,
      commutative diagrams/stack/every \ifodd\stackArrow odd\else even\fi/.try,
      commutative diagrams/stack/do path]}}},
  stack with setting/.style n args={3}{
    /tikz/commutative diagrams/stack/every odd/.append style={#1},
    /tikz/commutative diagrams/stack/every even/.append style={#2},
    /tikz/commutative diagrams/stack={#3}},
  stack alt/.style={
    /tikz/commutative diagrams/stack with setting={}
      {/tikz/commutative diagrams/stack/do path/.style={
        /tikz/insert path/.expanded={(\tikztotarget)edge(\tikztostart)}}}
      {#1}}}
\begin{document}
Consider the simplicial set~\( X_{\bullet} \) given by
\[\begin{tikzcd}
  \cdots \ar[stack >=9, r]
& X_3    \ar[stack <=7, r]
& X_2    \ar[stack <=5, r]
& X_1    \ar[stack >=3, r]
& X_0
\end{tikzcd}\]

\[\begin{tikzcd}[
  stack/every odd/.append style={edges=red},
  stack/every even/.append style={edges=green}]
  \cdots \ar[stack alt=9, r, ->.>>, shorten <=15\pgflinewidth]
& X_3    \ar[stack <=7, r]
& X_2    \ar[stack <=5, d, stacks=bend right, stack distance=+.5ex]
         \ar[stack >=3, d, stacks=bend left, stack distance=+.5ex,
           stack/every odd/.append style={edges=blue},
           stack/every even/.append style={edges=orange}]\\
&
& X_1    \ar[stack >=3, r]
& X_0
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: One thing I’ve been wondering: Is there a way allow the syntax `\ar[r,<-,stack=7]` as well where the top arrow then goes in the left direction? I.e. instead of hardcoding the direction of each arrow, could it simply start with the default direction and then “change direction” each time? I wonder how much more complicated the code would then become? (Note that I left the same comment to @SandyG’s answer.)

Comment: @Gaussler See my updated version. We coud also use `\ifodd` or similar to just swap `\tikztostart` with `\tikztotarget` but a `swap arrow tips` key might come handy in other instances as well. (The `\pgf@arrow@tip@sequence` is a temporary/auxilliary macro that's used by PGF itself already.) It might be better to implement `stack` and the distance between arrows differently (see my last note) to make it easier to use it with the default size of arrow tips.

Comment: This can't really deal with the automatic shortening of the arrows since that would mean that the arrow tip specification needs to be parsed again. (Though an empty tip might be easy to detect.) How should that work at best? That said, maybe it would be better to just swap start and target and let just TikZ handle the reversing.

Comment: Yeah, the automatic shortening of the arrows now looks very strange. It might indeed be better to just only allow the “forward” direction and then just manually move the arrow to the other source in the cases where this is necessary. Perhaps it would be better to revert to the previous version of the answer? That looked much less confusing. `;-)` (Thanks for the help anyway!)

Comment: @Gaussler Initially, I was going off the other answers which led me to just using `->` and `<-`. I've updated my answer yet again which makes it seem even more confusing but it is also much more flexible. Basically: `stack >` and `stack <` will use `->`/`<-` and `stack alt` will reverse the path and use no specific arrow specification.

Comment: It surprises me a bit that there is no way to determine the current direction of the arrow, i.e. whether the user specified `->`, `<-`, or something else. I mean, surely, that information must be stored somewhere. Then the `stack alt` key should be able to read this information.

Comment: Another thing: Currently, `stack` doesn’t use the arrows tips specified in the options. Instead it uses the standard TikZ arrow tips, at least until the user runs `->`.

Comment: @Gaussler Re *Another thing*: That's a TikZ-CD thing (and it only looks like the standard TikZ arrow tip), it uses its own arrows by default so that they look like the arrows of math mode. If you want TikZ-CD to use your own `>` just say `arrows=->` (as an option to the environment or globablly in `\tikzcdset`.

Comment: Re *direction*: Now, I'm confused. What do you consider to be the "direction of the arrow"? With `swap arrow tips` it is possibly to turn the arrow tip specification `<start>-<end>` into `<end>-<start>`. We'd also need to swap the shortening (if I'm seeing this correctly, it can be done just as easy). I just don't see a way to automatically determine the amount of shortening so that the arrow tip of one direction stands out cleanly from the line in the other direction. I don't know what to do with lines that have tips on both sides. IMO, just reversing the path solves a lot of problems.

Comment: [Here's a way to use `rev`erse keys with custom arrow tips.](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/tex.sx/blob/master/582696.tex) This will need you to do adjustments to the stack lines with `every stack`/`stacks. Unless the `shorten`ing is to be done to all arrows I don't see how to avoid it. This is using a lot of layers (CD ontop of TikZ, edges inside to paths, etc), a lot of options that inherit or overwrite each other. This gets really complex fast if you want maximum flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

What I've come with, at the moment, is the following. It's not really optimized, but it was to give you the idea of how it could be automated. Actually, it's no big deal to refine the new command `\arrowstack` to give it just the number of arrows you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{intcalc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\newcommand{\arrowstack}[1]{\ifthenelse{\equal{\intcalcMod{\i}{2}}{0}}%
                    {\draw[-stealth] ($(#1)+(-.5,\s pt)$) --++ (1,0);}%
                    {\draw[stealth-] ($(#1)+(-.5,\s pt)$) --++ (1,0);}          
                    }
\begin{document}    
    
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=.75cm]
        \node (X) {$\dots$};
        \coordinate[right= of X] (X');
                \foreach \s [count=\i] in {12,9,6,3,0,-3,-6,-9,-12}
                    {\arrowstack{X'}}
                
        \node[right= of X'] (X3) {$X_3$};
        \coordinate[right= of X3] (X3');
                \foreach \s [count=\i] in {9,6,3,0,-3,-6,-9}
                    {\arrowstack{X3'}}
                    
        \node[right= of X3'] (X2) {$X_2$};
        \coordinate[right= of X2] (X2');
                \foreach \s [count=\i] in {6,3,0,-3,-6}
                    {\arrowstack{X2'}}
                    
        \node[right= of X2'] (X1) {$X_1$};
        \coordinate[right= of X1] (X1');
                \foreach \s [count=\i] in {3,0,-3}
                    {\arrowstack{X1'}}

        \node[right= of X1'] (X0) {$X_0$};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Arrows Stack]

Comment: Actually, I just saw that I inverted the arrows. That's not really difficult to fix ;)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the following, pretty simple solution. I realized that it was easier to use ordinary LaTeX commands rather than resolving to TikZ keys. The floating point arithmetic could obviously be simplified, at the loss of clarity of what’s going on.

Feel free to suggest improvements (e.g. maybe a dimensional expression is better than a floating point expression?).

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\tikzcdset{
  diagrams={>={Straight Barb[scale=0.5]}}
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand\stackar{ m O{} }
{
    \int_step_inline:nn { #1 }
    {
        \int_if_odd:nTF { ##1 }
        {
            \ar[->,yshift=(#1-1)/2*1.5pt - (##1-1)*1.5pt,#2]
        }
        {
            \ar[<-,yshift=(#1-1)/2*1.5pt - (##1-1)*1.5pt,#2]
        }
    }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[\begin{tikzcd}
    \cdots
    \stackar{9}[r]
    &
    X_3
    \stackar{7}[r]
    &
    X_2
    \stackar{5}[r]
    &   
    X_1
    \stackar{3}[r]
    &
    X_0
\end{tikzcd}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Add a `+` in front of `\fp_eval:n` so that PGFMath doesn't evaluate the expression again (or just leave out the `\fp_eval:n` because PGFMath can evaluate that expression itself).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks, updated.