# tikz-cd: Shifting stacked arrows in the direction of the target

Tags: tikz-cd

I am using a (slightly updated) version of [my answer to my own question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/610198/19809) to draw stacked arrows for simplicial diagrams:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,tikz-cd}

\tikzcdset{
  diagrams={>={Straight Barb[scale=0.5]}}
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand\stackar{ m O{} }
{
    \int_step_inline:nn { #1 }
    {
        \ar[->,shift~left=\fp_eval:n {(#1-1)/2*3 - (##1-1)*3 }pt,#2]
    }
}

\NewDocumentCommand\altstackar{ m O{} }
{
    \int_step_inline:nn { #1 }
    {
        \int_if_odd:nTF { ##1 }
        {
            \ar[->,shift~left=\fp_eval:n {(#1-1)/2*1.5 - (##1-1)*1.5 }pt,#2]
        }
        {
            \ar[<-,shift~left=\fp_eval:n {(#1-1)/2*1.5 - (##1-1)*1.5 }pt,#2]
        }
    }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[\begin{tikzcd}
    \dotsb
    \stackar{4}[r]
        & X_2 \stackar{3}[r]
            & X_1 \stackar{2}[r]
                & X_0
\end{tikzcd}\]

\[\begin{tikzcd}
    \dotsb
    \altstackar{7}[r]
        & X_2 \altstackar{5}[r]
            & X_1 \altstackar{3}[r]
                & X_0
\end{tikzcd}\]

\[\begin{tikzcd}
    X_2 \altstackar{5}[d]
\\
    X_1
\end{tikzcd}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, the result is still a bit too cluttered for my taste. It looks weird that the arrow heads are completely surrounded by the bodies of the neighbouring arrows. So I would prefer something like the following. However, as you see, using `xshift` sometimes fails, e.g. when the arrows are vertical. Is there a way to shift the arrows “forward”, i.e. towards their target?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,tikz-cd}

\tikzcdset{
  diagrams={>={Straight Barb[scale=0.5]}}
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand\stackar{ m O{} }
{
    \int_step_inline:nn { #1 }
    {
        \ar[->,shift~left=\fp_eval:n {(#1-1)/2*3 - (##1-1)*3 }pt,#2]
    }
}

\NewDocumentCommand\altstackar{ m O{} }
{
    \int_step_inline:nn { #1 }
    {
        \int_if_odd:nTF { ##1 }
        {
            \ar[->,shift~left=\fp_eval:n {(#1-1)/2*1.5 - (##1-1)*1.5 }pt,xshift=.5pt,#2]
        }
        {
            \ar[<-,shift~left=\fp_eval:n {(#1-1)/2*1.5 - (##1-1)*1.5 }pt,xshift=-.5pt,#2]
        }
    }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[\begin{tikzcd}
    \dotsb
    \stackar{4}[r]
        & X_2 \stackar{3}[r]
            & X_1 \stackar{2}[r]
                & X_0
\end{tikzcd}\]

\[\begin{tikzcd}
    \dotsb
    \altstackar{7}[r]
        & X_2 \altstackar{5}[r]
            & X_1 \altstackar{3}[r]
                & X_0
\end{tikzcd}\]

\[\begin{tikzcd}
    X_2 \altstackar{5}[d]
\\
    X_1
\end{tikzcd}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose an alternate solution, which is to define new arrow styles that can be used anywhere in a `tikzcd`. The styles are called `stackar` and `altstackar` and they take an argument for the number of arrows. Instead of shifting the arrows for the alternating, the tails are shortened by `2pt`. You can change that near the end of the `altstackar` definition.

The idea is to compute a vector `(\xperp,\yperp)` perpendicular to the arrow direction with length `3pt` (or `1.5pt` for the alternating arrows), and then shift the arrows by multiples of that vector.

Usage: `\arrow[r, stackar=<number>]` or `\arrow[r, altstackar=<number>]`. Arrow directions can be anything accepted in a typical `tikzcd`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, calc}

\tikzcdset{
  diagrams={>={Straight Barb[scale=0.5]}}
}
\tikzset{
  stackar/.style={decorate, decoration={show path construction,
    lineto code={
      \path (\tikzinputsegmentfirst); \pgfgetlastxy{\xstart}{\ystart}
      \path (\tikzinputsegmentlast); \pgfgetlastxy{\xend}{\yend}
      \path ($(0,0)!3pt!(\ystart-\yend,\xend-\xstart)$); \pgfgetlastxy{\xperp}{\yperp}
      \foreach \n[evaluate=\n as \k using .5*#1-\n+.5] in {1,...,#1}{
        \draw[->, shift={($\k*(\xperp,\yperp)$)}](\xstart,\ystart)--(\xend,\yend);
      }
    }
  }}, stackar/.default={1},
  altstackar/.style={decorate, decoration={show path construction,
    lineto code={
      \path (\tikzinputsegmentfirst); \pgfgetlastxy{\xstart}{\ystart}
      \path (\tikzinputsegmentlast); \pgfgetlastxy{\xend}{\yend}
      \path ($(0,0)!1.5pt!(\ystart-\yend,\xend-\xstart)$); \pgfgetlastxy{\xperp}{\yperp}
      \foreach \n[evaluate=\n as \k using .5*#1-\n+.5] in {1,...,#1}{
        \ifodd\n{\draw[->, shorten <=2pt, shift={($\k*(\xperp,\yperp)$)}](\xstart,\ystart)--(\xend,\yend);}
        \else{\draw[<-, shorten >=2pt, shift={($\k*(\xperp,\yperp)$)}](\xstart,\ystart)--(\xend,\yend);}\fi
      }
    }
  }}, altstackar/.default={1}
}


\begin{document}

\[\begin{tikzcd}
    \dotsb\arrow[r, stackar=4] & X_2\arrow[r, stackar=3] & X_1\arrow[r, stackar=2] & X_0
\end{tikzcd}\]

\[\begin{tikzcd}
    \dotsb\arrow[r, altstackar=7] & X_2\arrow[r, altstackar=5] & X_1\arrow[r, altstackar=3] & X_0
\end{tikzcd}\]

\[\begin{tikzcd}
    X_2 \arrow[d, altstackar=5] &\\
    X_1 & X_3\arrow[ul, altstackar=3]
\end{tikzcd}\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: That was actually the syntax I originally requested in my first question. You can go ahead and also post it as an answer there, too, if you would like a few extra points. `;-)`

Comment: @Gaussler: At the time I didn't think of using `pathreplacing`. But your `ExplSyntax` solution is good too.

Comment: Yes, I remember we discussed it back then, too. Anyway, I might add it as an extra answer and credit you, just for the sake of completeness. `;-)`

Comment: @Gaussler: I updated the other answer.